# R using table of same dimensions

Tags: r, if-statement, datatables, subset

I have two tables both 4x4 dimension. I wold like to know how I can replace a cell in the first table with a 0 if there is a 0 in the corresponding cell of the bottom table (using an R command, I'm guessing an If statement or sub-setting). E.g the first row and column of the first table (-0.2) should be converted to zero based on the 0 value of the first row and column of the second table (-0.2)? Thanks

first table

-0.2,   0.5,    0.8,    0.01,
1,  -0.4,   0.8,    0.5,
0.5,    0.3,    -0.1,   0.8,
-0.8,   0.5,    0.5,    -0.02, (4x4)

second table
0,  0,  1.8,    0,
0,  2.7,    0,  0,
0,  0,  3.2,    0,
0,  0,  0,  0,
(4x4)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables (matrices or data frames) are called `tab1` and `tab2`, you can use the following command:

```
tab1[!tab2] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks but everytime I try that command I get the following message "Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument type". It does, however, work if I create a matrix from scratch but when I enter the data which I have extracted from a larger data frame it does not work.

Comment: It's working now as I used "data.matrix". Thanks again!